# How to extract real number from string?

Tags: c, string

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13399677/2411320) (you can use the minor example in Ideone there, it's equivalent), so I wrote the function below to do the job, but it will stop when reading the dot before the decimal digits and will treat pi like 3 and 14. How to change the code to extract the real number? I do not care about speed or memory usage, I just want to do the job.

```
float extract_number(char* str) {
    char* p = str;
    while (*p) {
        if (isdigit(*p)) {
            long val = strtol(p, &p, 10);
            printf("%ld\n", val);
            return val;
        } else {
            p++;
        }
    }
    return -1.0;
}
```

Here is the `str` I am working with:

```
Initializing data structure(s) took 149.898690000 seconds wall clock time.
```

Comment: You're going to loose a lot of precision converting from `long` to `float`.

Comment: Do not really care @ThePcLuddite, anyway, modified.

Comment: Consider `strtod` instead of `strtol`. (It returns `double`, not `float`, not sure if it is OK in your case.)

Comment: @AlexD the core was taken from the answer I linked into.

Comment: Uh, what? `strtol` converts to a [long](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), not a float. So there's your problem.

Comment: Correct @Jongware, you deserve the credits, are you going to answer please? `strtof` solved the problem!

Comment: @AlexD gave the hint (but for the wrong reason). You can use either `strtod` or `strtof`.

Comment: Oh @AlexD, sorry, missed your edit. Anyway, one from you, should answer then, you deserve the credits. AlexD has the token :P

Comment: @Jongware Your comment is more precise, please go ahead with answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtol` converts text to a `long`, not a `float`. From [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol):

> Interprets an integer value in a byte string pointed to by `str`.

Use either [`strtof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) or `strtod` to convert to a `float` or `double`. The prototype uses a second argument, commonly called `endptr`, which is a `char *` that will be updated to point to the first not-converted character, but since you don't need it here you can set it to `NULL`.

A couple more optimizations on that routine:

1. you can safely modify the argument `*str`
2. no need for an intermediate value, you can return the result of `strtof`
3. no need for an `else` after an explicit `return`
4. if the value `-1.0f` is a possible valid return value, you should use `NAN`.

```
float extract_number (char* str)
{
    while (*str)
    {
        if (isdigit(*str))
        {
            return strtof(str, NULL);
        }
        str++;
    }
    return NAN;
}
```

To return `NAN` you need to include `math.h`, but it is a fairly recent addition (and, apparently, an omission before!) so it may not be available in your system. If it isn't, use this totally wicked hack (kudos to [J.Kraftcheck's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25081020/2564301)):

```
return strtof("NaN", NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like sscanf for string parsing:

```
double extract_number(char* str) {
  double x;
  int result = sscanf (str, "%lf", &x);
  if (result != 1)
    return -1.0;
  return x;
}
```

NOTE:

If you want to separate the integral and fractional parts of a floating point value, look at [modf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/modf).

Comment: -1 Input overflow triggers undefined behavior, therefore it is unsafe to use the `scanf` functions to parse numbers, period.

Comment: Paul, really sorry, but my question was not clear. Updated and your code won't work now.

Comment: @gsamaras: 1) sscanf() is perfectly appropriate: you can check for "illegal string" by verifying "result == 1" (successfully read the "%lf" argument).  2) Use "modf()" to split integer/fraction  (if your platform supports it).  3) Using "-1" to flag "illegal input" probably isn't the most robust solution.  I would consider adding an "error flag" either as your function return, or as a reference parameter.  In any case, I much prefer "sscanf()" to "strtod()". Because you don't have to mess with errno - which everybody and his brother uses, and which isn't always thread-safe). IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 I'm sorry, it does not work to "check for 'illegal string' by verifying 'result == 1'", because, again, *input overflow triggers **undefined behavior**.*  See the longer discussion on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302160/scanf-on-an-istream-object/24318630#24318630  The *only* fully reliable (that is, all errors are detectable and the behavior is fully defined regardless of input) numeric conversion functions in the C library are the `strto*` functions.

Comment: @paulsm4 Also, FYI, `errno` is required to be thread-safe by both POSIX.1(-2001) and C11 (which is the first C standard revision to have any concept of threads) and I haven't tripped over an implementation that got that wrong in at least 15 years.