# how to separate integers and operators from a string in c?

Tags: c, string

I want to make a parser and first step I have in mind is to extract integers and operators from an input string and store them in their respective arrays. What I have so far is this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/*  Grammar for simple arithmetic expression
E = E + T | E - T | T
T = T * F | T / F | F
F = (E)

Legend:
E -> expression
T -> term
F -> factor
*/

void reader(char *temp_0){
char *p = temp_0;
while(*p){
    if (isdigit(*p)){
        long val = strtol(p, &p, 10);
        printf("%ld\n",val);
    }else{
    p++;
    }
}

}

int main(){
char expr[20], temp_0[20];

printf("Type an arithmetic expression \n");
gets(expr);

strcpy(temp_0, expr);

reader( temp_0 );

return 0;
    }
```

Say I have an input of "65 + 9 - 4" and I want to store the integers 65, 9, 4 to an integer array and the operators +, - in an operators array and also ignores the whitespaces in the input. How should I do it?

P.S.
I am using the code in my reader function which I got from here :[How to extract numbers from string in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399594/how-to-extract-numbers-from-string-in-c)

Comment: What is your query (as you have already separated digits from the string do the same to extract the operators)? Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used on why `gets() is dangerous`

Comment: What is your question?
Maybe you forgot to add "This is FYI" at the end :P

Comment: Say I have an input of "65 + 9 - 4" and I want to store the integers 65, 9, 4 to an integer array and the operators +, - in an array. 

Thanks for the warning about gets().

Comment: Which notation you want to use? Postfix notation or others?

Comment: prefix notation/polish notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a sample test. 
Sorry for the tough code, since not have too much time.
But it works well on my VS.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
    //Here I think By default this string is started with an integer.
    char *str = "65 + 9 - 4";
    char *ptr = str;
    char ch;
    char buff[32];
    int  valArray[32];
    int  val, len = 0, num = 0;
    while ((ch = *ptr++) != '\0'){
        if (isdigit(ch) && *ptr != '\0'){
            buff[len++] = ch;
        }
        else{
            if (len != 0){
                val = atoi(buff);
                printf("%d\n", val);
                valArray[num++] = val;
                memset(buff, 0, 32);
                len = 0;
            }
            else if (ch == ' ')
                continue;
            else
                printf("%c\n",ch);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I know what is char ch for?

Comment: In fact it just means the character which the pointer ptr is pointing to currently, I use this is because I want to finish the ptr++ operation in the while loop judgement part.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the integer array and operator array to the `render()` function as parameters like `render( temp_0, arrNum, arrOperator, &numCount, &opCount)`, where `arrNum` is an array of long and `arrOperator` is an array of char and the `numCount` and `opCount` are two integers which will denote the number of integers and operators respectively. These last two integer will be populated in `render()`. Then the modified `render()` function might look like -

```
void reader(char *temp_0, long *arri, char *arro, int *numCount, int *opCount){
char *p = temp_0;
int integerCount = 0;
int operatorCount = 0;

while(*p){
    if (isdigit(*p)){
        long val = strtol(p, &p, 10);
        arri[integerCount++] = val;
    }else{
       if((*p == '+') || (*p == '-') || 
          (*p == '/') || (*p == '*'))/* Add other operators here if you want*/
       {
          arro[operatorCount++] = *p;
       }
    p++;
    }
}

    *numCount = integerCount;
    *opCount  = operatorCount;

}
```

Note that there is no error checking done in the code. You might want to add that.

Comment: I'm having problems in printing it...I placed printf("%d\n", arri[*p]); after the arri[integerCount++] = val;  and printf("%c\n", arro[*p]); after the arro[operatorCount++] = *p; 

the output is different from my input

Comment: The printf should be like `printf("%d\n", arri[integerCount - 1]);` and `printf("%c\n", arro[operatorCount - 1]);` as `operatorCount` and `integerCount` are the index of the array, not `*p`. Also in the `printf()` the indexes are less than that of `operatorCount` and `integerCount` as they are already incremented in the previous statement.