# How to calculate the numerical value of a string in C

Tags: c, string, char

I'm trying to calculate the value a string in C.

I define the string like: `char cadena[100] = "Esto es un text securizado$2516"`

I need to transform 2516 into an int, I'm actually trying to use `atoi()`, but I don't know how to separate the string to use the function.

PS: Excuse my English, it's not my native language, I hope you understand what I want to do.

Comment: `value=atoi(strchr(cadena,'$')+1);` But this is simplistic, will fall over horribly if there is no `'$'`

Comment: Use `strcspn()` to skip over the non-number characters, then use `atoi` on the rest.

Comment: You may use `strchr()` to obtain a pointer to the first occurrence of a character in your string. You may use that to find where the "$" is.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399594/how-to-extract-numbers-from-string-in-c

Comment: Or even use `strrchr(cadena, '$')`, which finds the first occurrence of a dollar sign from the end in case the string proper has dollars and/or numbers.

Comment: You need to define the rule before you can implement it. It's impossible for us to tell the rule from just one example. For example, I can think of three possible answers if the string is "Esto es 2516 en $2500 or 1400", depending on exactly what the rule is. (Is the rule to use the first number? The last number? The one preceded by a `$`? Or what?)

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward approach can look the following way

```
int number = 0;
char cadena[100] = "Esto es un text securizado$2516";

size_t n = strcspn( cadena, "0123456789" );

if ( cadena[n] ) number = atoi( cadena + n );
```

Or if the number is already initialized by 0 then you can just write

```
number = atoi( cadena + n );
```

In this case zero will be a default value.

Comment: @chux I've updated my post according to your remark.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strrchr` to find the rightmost occurrence of a character. It returns a pointer to that rightmost character, or `NULL` if it was not found:

```
char *p;
int n;
if ((p = strrchr(cadena, '$')) != NULL)
    sscanf(p + 1, "%d", &n);
```

Notice we add 1 to `p`. This is because p points to the `$` character.

And don't use `atoi`, since it does no error checking. On the other hand, `sscanf` returns 0 on failure.

Comment: Note: `sscanf(p + 1, "%d", &n)` will return 0 on a failure to convert (no digits).  `sscanf()` and `atoi()` do not report overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char cadena[100] = "Esto es un text securizado$2516";
    int value = 0;
    size_t i;

    for(i = 0; cadena[i]; ++i){
        if(1 == sscanf(cadena + i, "%d", &value))//try and get
            break;
    }
    printf("%d\n", value);

    return 0;
}
```