# sscanf not reading numbers

Tags: c, scanf

A newbie in C is trying to extract two numbers from a string using sscanf(). The numbers shall be parsed from strings formatted like "7-12", which should result in `firstNode = 7`and `secondNode = 12`. So I want to get the numbers, the minus sign can be understood as a number seperator. My current implementation is similar to the example I found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13399812/8331157) SO answer:

```
void extractEdge(char *string) {
    int firstNode = 123;
    int secondNode = 123;

    sscanf(string, "%*[^0123456789]%u%*[^0123456789]%u", &firstNode, &secondNode);
    printf("Edge parsing results: Arguments are %s, %d, %d", string, firstNode, secondNode);
}
```

But if I execute the code above, there always is retourned the inital value 123 for both ints. Note that the output of `string` gives the correct input String, so I think an invalid string can't be a probable cause for this problem.

Any ideas why the code is not working? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `%*[^0123456789]` has to match _at least one_ character. If your string starts with `7`, that means `%*[]` fails, and makes `sscanf` return. Why not just `scanf("%d-%d"`?

Comment: That works! Wouldn't have thought that posix could be that easy sometimes, regarding the examples on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%*[^0123456789]` requires one or more non-digit character, but the first character of you input `7-12` is a digit. This makes `sscanf()` stop there and read nothing.

Remove that and use `"%d%*[^0123456789]%d"` as format specifier to deal with `7-12`.

Also note that correct format specifier for reading decimal `int` is `%d`, not `%u`. `%u` is for reading `unsigned int`.