# C, how to get undefined part of string

Tags: c, string

I started learning C language about 1 week, and I'm trying to build my first programs. I'm coming from Python, so the C syntax isn't very clear for me, and I haven't understand the solutions that I found online.
So, if I have this string:

```
char str[50] = "dimension[1080,720];"
```

and i want to *create two integer variables that containes 1080 and 720 and string var that contains the first string.* But *these two numbers can change*, and they can have random cifras. So, i wanted my output is

```
int x = 1080
int y = 720
```

*the values are always two, but the lenght can change.
How can i do that?

---

Second version:

So, if I have this string:

```
char str[50] = "dimension["string",1080,720];"
```

and i want to *create two integer variables that containes 1080 and 720 and string var that contains the first string.* But *these two numbers can change*, and they can have random cifras. So, i wanted my output is

```
char str[1000] = "string";    
int x = 1080
int y = 720
```

*the values are always three*, but the lenght can change.
How can i do that?

Comment: So your question is "How to parse two integers contained in the string"?

Comment: You could try : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399594/how-to-extract-numbers-from-string-in-c

Comment: @user3121023 yes, i've write 20 for the post, but in original post is 50, now i correct

Comment: `"dimension["string",1080,720];"` does not look like a valid string. You should take the time to provide a proper example of what you are trying to work with

Comment: Do you mean `char str[50] = "dimension[\"string\",1080,720]";` that would actually compile, or something else? Hard to answer something that doesn't compile and keeps changing.

Comment: It is absolutely unclear what you are trying to do. Maybe you can show a Python equivalent.

Comment: Being pedantic, Sheep & Ninja, this can compile depending on what the token `string` resolves to (e.g., macro of string literal: https://godbolt.org/z/vfnxzd7Ez). Unlikely to be the case, but this is why, @JacopoBiondi, a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showcasing an actual attempt is very important to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4):

use `sscanf` function

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "dimension[1080,720];";
    int x,y;

    if(sscanf(str, "dimension[%d,%d", &x, &y) != 2) {printf("Error\n");}
    else printf("X=%d Y=%d", x, y);
}
```

Question two:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "dimension[\"string\",1080,720];";
    char str1[20];
    int x,y;

    char *ptr = strstr(str, "[");
    char *ptr1;
    size_t len;
    
    memcpy(str1, ptr + 2, len = (ptr1 = strchr(ptr + 2, '"')) - (ptr + 2));
    str[len] = 0;

    if(sscanf(ptr1 + 2, "%d,%d", &x, &y) != 2) {printf("Error\n");}
    else printf("Str = %s X=%d Y=%d", str1, x, y);
}
```

Comment: I haven't understand this solution.. where you pick the values from the string?

Comment: I would suggest to read about scanf function https://computer.howstuffworks.com/c7.htm

Comment: @SupportUkraine OP is changing the question

Comment: thanks, i've understand this solution and it works for me!!!

Comment: but i've encountered another problem with sscanf: it picks a string until a space. If I have "Lucas hadid" i get only "Lucas". I read to use fgets, it's correct?

Answer (score 1):

The `sscanf` answer is perfect, but not very flexible. I add this in case you want more flexibility to parse strings. You can do it with regular expressions and in your case would be something like:

Piece of code taken from https://gist.github.com/ianmackinnon/3294587
I have added some modification to extract the numbers to the variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main ()
{

  // Define regexp and input
  char * source = "dimension[\"string\",1080,720];";
  char * regexString = "[a-z]+\\[\"([a-z]+)\",([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\\]";
  size_t maxMatches = 3;
  size_t maxGroups = 4;

  // Variables we want to extract from the input
  char*  str;
  int    n1;
  int    n2;
  

  regex_t regexCompiled;
  regmatch_t groupArray[maxGroups];
  unsigned int m;
  char * cursor;

  if (regcomp(&regexCompiled, regexString, REG_EXTENDED))
    {
      printf("Could not compile regular expression.\n");
      return 1;
    };

  m = 0;
  cursor = source;
  for (m = 0; m < maxMatches; m ++)
    {
      if (regexec(&regexCompiled, cursor, maxGroups, groupArray, 0))
        break;  // No more matches

      unsigned int g = 0;
      unsigned int offset = 0;
      for (g = 0; g < maxGroups; g++)
        {
          if (groupArray[g].rm_so == (size_t)-1)
            break;  // No more groups

          if (g == 0)
            offset = groupArray[g].rm_eo;

          char cursorCopy[strlen(cursor) + 1];
          strcpy(cursorCopy, cursor);
          cursorCopy[groupArray[g].rm_eo] = 0;
          printf("Match %u, Group %u: [%2u-%2u]: %s\n",
                 m, g, groupArray[g].rm_so, groupArray[g].rm_eo,
                 cursorCopy + groupArray[g].rm_so);

          switch (g)
          {
            case 1:
                // Copy to the string now that we know the length
                str = malloc(strlen(cursor)+1);
                strcpy(str,cursorCopy + groupArray[g].rm_so);
                break;
            case 2:
                n1 = (int) strtol(cursorCopy + groupArray[g].rm_so, (char **)NULL, 10); //(cursorCopy + groupArray[g].rm_so,10);
                break;
            case 3:
                n2 = (int) strtol(cursorCopy + groupArray[g].rm_so, (char **)NULL, 10); //(cursorCopy + groupArray[g].rm_so,10);
                break;

          }

        }
      cursor += offset;
    }

  regfree(&regexCompiled);


  printf("Matches in variables: %s - %d - %d \n",str,n1,n2);

  return 0;
}
```

This for me prints

```
Match 0, Group 0: [ 0-28]: dimension["string",1080,720]
Match 0, Group 1: [11-17]: string
Match 0, Group 2: [19-23]: 1080
Match 0, Group 3: [24-27]: 720
Matches in variables: string - 1080 - 720
```